# Show UFW comment in IPTABLES

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I started to use ufw for easier maintaince.

For my telegraf plugin the iptables entry needs to have a comment added with `-m comment --comment "myComment"`.

UFW does have a comment feature, but as far as I get it, only for internal usage.
If I do

```
ufw allow ssh comment "MySSH"
```

it creates the rules in `/etc/ufw/user.rules`:

```
### tuple ### allow tcp 22 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in comment=737368
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

but do not add that comment.
I also verified checking iptables:

```
root@xxx:~# iptables -nvL ufw-user-input
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
```

Is it somehow possible to pass the comment to iptables ?

As a workaround it worked to add manual my comment in `/etc/ufw/user.rules` and do `ufw reload`, but has to be done for every new/changing rule..

I'm thankfull for every hint!

Comment: It seems that `-m comment` option of iptables is used for some app-related stuff: https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/tree/src/common.py#n175
I think the easiest approach might be to ditch UFW entirely and just use pure iptables.

Answer (score 0):

While ufw does have a 'comment' facility, you are correct that it is used internally. This has to do with the fact that ufw currently uses iptables comment for its 'app rules' (collections of rules). ufw would need to be updated to support this.

In terms of telegraf, parsing /var/log/ufw.log may provide what you need. https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/16164 (untested by me) describes a way to do this.